# Erase characters in a string

Tags: c#, string

I'm running a class whose job is to parse through an html document to get some information.

In one of my condition I end up having this string:

```
"\r\n                            First Name:"
```

I wanted to format the string so that I only had "First Name:", so I did this:

```
string firstName = node.InnerText;

firstName = firstName.Replace(" ", "");
firstName = firstName.Replace("\\r", "");
firstName = firstName.Replace("\\n", "");
firstName.Trim();
```

But I end up having the same string as before. I'm rather new to mvc-app and I thought that this would do the job, but it does not. How can I achieve my goal?

Thank you!

*** EDIT ***

I have modified my code to show you what I've done so far, because I wanted to notify everyone that the first line worked, but no the rest. I end up having this string:

```
"\r\nFirst Name:"
```

Comment: you don't have to escape `\r`, use single backslash, not double, also `firstName.Trim()` would do the job, but you need to assign it back to `firstName` like `firstName = firstName.Trim();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx):

```
string firstName = "\r\n                            First Name:".TrimStart();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ZjeAEd)

[`String.TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) works because `Environment.NewLine` belongs to the [white-space characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx) that `TrimStart` removes. It returns a new string(strings are immutable), so you need to use the return value and assign it to your variable.

Comment: @Habib: I'thought so too, but it didn't work(on ideone), so i've added the replace.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, the reason it didn't work is that you are using `@` in string.Replace, escaping the backslash,  instead it should be: `"\r\n"`, currently it is working because `TrimStart` is removing the white space

Answer (score 6):

you **need to assign the result back** to firstName, since strings are immutable, `string.Replace` would **not change the original string** instead it will return a new string.

```
firstName = firstName.Replace(" ", "");
firstName = firstName.Replace("\r", "");
firstName = firstName.Replace("\n", "");
```

By the way you can use **[string.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)**:

```
string firstName = "\r\n                            First Name:";
firstName = firstName.Trim();
```

since `String.Trim` would remove all the white spaces including `\r` and `\n` from beginning and end of string

**EDIT:**

You need to use single backslash `\r` not double `\\r`

Comment: also consider using regular expression, and you don't need to use \r,\n or ' ', just use white space "\s"

Comment: Ah! Ok! thanks! It worked for the spaces, but it seems not to work for the \n and the \r

Comment: @HerveS, was in middle of editing, you need to do the same for `\r` and `\n`, but better is to use string.Trim, check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

[`Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) will remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of the string.

```
string firstName = node.InnerText.Trim();
```

I tested it under .NET 4.5 and `Trim()` does remove `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
firstName = firstName.Trim();
```